# How do I make a program recognize dropped packets?

Tags: c, network-programming

I have a program to simulate a network with a packet sent back and forth from a client to a host.

This simulation includes a chance for a packet to be dropped when sent. My client program is set up to send the packet back five times before terminating, but when a packet is dropped the client will not stop waiting until manually terminated.

I had a client program that called a method that constantly waited for a packet, and would not let the rest of the program execute until it recieved a packet five times. If a packet was dropped, the client program would not terminate.

What do I need in order for the client program to recognize when a packet is dropped or is taking too long to return?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. Are you using UDP packets? Add details about your communication protocol. You probably have to implement a timeout, maybe using `select`.

Comment: That's a fairly open-ended question.  You'll need to be able to identify packets that were sent (sequence number); you'll need to be able to resend dropped packets; you'll need to know which packets were received (ACK); you'll need to define how long to wait for an ACK for a packet; you'll probably want to send more packets while waiting for ACKs (sliding windows, asynchronous ACKs).

Answer (score 1):

One word: timeout.

You can't directly detect a dropped packet.

You should establish a timing discipline. For example, you might require your host to send five packets, one per second.

And you might require your client listener to wait six seconds, giving the network an extra second after the time of transmission of the last packet.

If you were using TCP, the timeout is built in to the stack.

Answer (score -1):

TCP (Transmission control protocol) implements this very nicely. The thing about dropping packets is it happens on the wire, in one of the lower levels of the TCP/IP layer model. Your computer does not have access to this information: once a packet is sent, the sender has no information about this packet. Before it's received, the receiver doesn't know about it either. These limitations make "transmission control" a somewhat involved task.

TCP works by sending the packet with the `SYN` flag set, as well as a unique incremental identifier. The receiver then sends back a packet with `SYN-ACK` and the identifier incremented by +1 (the `Seq` flag in the packet). Then finally the original sender sends an `ack` packet back (again incrementing the `seq` flag) to confirm reception of the `SYN-ACK`.

This pattern is redundant and allows the client or server in the architecture to ensure that all packets are sent and received properly.

Networking operations such as the Linux syscall `send(2)` will go through the Linux kernel which by default (AFAIK) sends via TCP.

Implementing TCP patterns would be a good exercise for your understanding of the networking stack overall.

You can also set a timeout, if the server hasn't received x packets in y seconds, have the client send them all again.

[image: SYN/ACK example]

*picture from Wikipedia*

Comment: This diagram covers the TCP session establishment 3-way handshake.  This is not used once the session is established.  Once the session is established, the behaviour is different — it still involves acknowledgements, but not the SYN and ACK packets shown.

Comment: This *answer* covers the TCP session establishment. It says nothing about how dropped packets are handled. And there is no OSI model in TCP/IP, but there is a TCP/IP layer model.